# What is the best HTTP status code to use when the requested language is unavailable?

Tags: http, localization, internationalization, http-status-codes

I'm working on a site which will be available in multiple languages. I'm using subdomains to identify the locale (seems like the best option for us after reading: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192), so our English site will be at `en.mysite.org`, French at `fr.mysite.org` etc.

Not all translations will be available right away and some will never be available. So I have two scenarios which may require two different status codes:

1. When the user visits `ru.mysite.org` I would like to show them a page that tells them that the language is not yet available but will provide more information on how they can help make it available.
2. When the user visits `pirate.mysite.org` I would like them to know that it will likely never be available (and Google should probably also be unaware of the site).

Right now I'm simply rendering a 404 in both cases but I'm thinking that there may be a better practise for these cases particularly for SEO purposes. For scenario 1 I'm starting to think that 501 may make more sense. For the second scenario I'm not sure if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a 404 is reasonable for both cases:

> #### 404 Not Found
>
> The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.
>
> [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

HTTP does have language support via the `Accept-Language` header, but your site does not use it. (Why not?) For all HTTP knows, the `fr` and `ru` subdomains are just other parts of your site. Using the subdomain to represent language is not "the HTTP way" to return a different representation of the same resource. So as far as HTTP is concerned, a user has requested something which is not available, but it might be available in the future.

I do not think that either case represents a server error so 5xx is not the appropriate category.

Comment: If HTTP language negotiation is applied, the correct code is 406 Not Acceptable. BTW, you should refer to authoritative resources such as RFC 7231, not to Wikipedia, which is anonymous data that may change at any moment.

Comment: I may use the `Accept-Language` header to redirect if a user visits the www. site for example but as far as I understand it, the header is used to automatically choose the best language and this can be bad practise if the user has expressed they want at different one. What's looks like a better solution is providing alternate links in the `<head>`: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, in which scenario is `406` the more correct code?

Comment: @Godwin, when HTTP language negotiation is used, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.6 (but the principle is indeed somewhat theoretic, since it is based on headers sent by a browser, and most users don’t even know about them, still less set them to reflect their language preferences).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela as I always tell anyone who comments usefully and constructively: please feel free to edit my answer to add additional content that might otherwise be "lost" as a comment. I take no offense at good edits, which I know you write.